# Script does not restart after it fails once it does not start up again. I can not find the reason

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, nested-loops

Need help on simplifying this script. I still need to add more clusters in while loops.

```
function Files() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var names = ss.getSheetByName("AME");
var SupplierName = names.getRange(names.getLastRow(),5).getValue();
var Cluster = names.getRange(names.getLastRow(),3).getValue();  

 if (Cluster == 'US'){
  var ClusterID = DriveApp.getFolderById("1z2R");
  var newFolderID = ClusterID.createFolder(SupplierName);

  var sourceFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("US").next();
  var files = sourceFolder.getFiles();
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(SupplierName).next();
    while(files.hasNext()){
    var file = files.next();
    file.moveTo(destFolder);
    }  
    return newFolderID.getId();
```

Comment: I can understand your 1st question of `Need help on simplifying this script.`. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your 2nd question of `I still need to add more clusters in while loops.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your 2nd question?

Comment: I could use a block diagram of something to help explain what you are trying to accomplish.  And what the data looks like

Answer (score 0):

**SUGGESTION:**

We are still kind of lurking in the dark here but here are some opportunities I have identified on the provided script above.

```
/**  Can be a global variable  */
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var names = ss.getSheetByName("AME");
var SupplierName = names.getRange(names.getLastRow(),5).getValue();
var Cluster = names.getRange(names.getLastRow(),3).getValue();  

function Files() {

 if(Cluster == 'US') {
  var ClusterID = DriveApp.getFolderById("SET FOLDER ID");
  var folders = ClusterID.getFoldersByName(SupplierName).hasNext(); 
  if(folders !== true){
    ClusterID.createFolder(SupplierName);
    moveFolders(SupplierName);
  }
  else {
   moveFolders(SupplierName);
    } 
  }
  else {
    Logger.log('Cluster is ' + Cluster);
  } 
}

function moveFolders() {
    var sourceFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("US").next();
    var files = sourceFolder.getFiles();
    Logger.log(files);
    var destFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(SupplierName).next();
      while(files.hasNext()){
      var file = files.next();
      file.moveTo(destFolder);
    } 
}
```

Created a separate function `moveFolders()` to move files to the created folder `ClusterID.createFolder(SupplierName);` if Cluster 'US' was checked on the last row of the sheet. I assumed that your data is from a response that came from a Google Form that is why the last row is only being checked.

Sample Data:
[image]

Source parent folder for Cluster Folder and US Folder:
[image]

Files inside the "US" Folder:
[image]

After the script is run, created the SupplierName folder containing the files moved from the US Folder:
[image]

Now I haven't worked on dynamically adjusting the script to manually define the cluster name as of the moment due to lack of clarity of the question, but I'll modify my answer once questions are addressed.